# Как убрать иконку загрузки с инлайн кнопок Telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Пишу бота c глубоким меню, и хочу убрать иконку загрузки с кнопок при нажатии

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашел тут ответ, что нужно добавить bot.callback_query_handler, но он у меня уже стоит для другого, все равно решил это проверить на всякий, и оно не работает, значок загрузки все также на месте

Как быть ?

Answer (score 1):

В телеботе это вот так.
Помещаете в колбек хендлер, который ловит нажатие на вашу кнопку.

```
@bot.callback_query_handlar(func=lambda call: True)
def name_func(call):
    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id)
```

Уточню помещаете ТОЛЬКО `bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id)`.
А то тут развелись любитель всовывать один хендлер внутрь другого. Не делайте так